# Processor fan always on in Lenovo x220 core i5 11ghz

Tags: update-manager

After upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 my processor fan is always on resulting in the battery draining rapidly as compared to when I was using the 16.04, is there something I need to do the make the system work as it used to do with the 16.04?
alternatively, if there is no solution to that can i perform a rollback to 16.04 through the terminal without clean installation?